Explainable multi instance regression?
I have data where each top-level instance has a few independent variables and a numeric target variable. In addition, there are 1 to k multi-feature vectors associated with each top-level instance. Basically, there are two tables in a 1-to-n relationship, where the target variable is in the 1 table and independent variables are both in 1 and n tables.
I would like to find a model that, given the independent variables in the main and detail tables, predicts the target numeric value as well as possible, but which is also to some extend interpretable or at least finds rough estimates of feature importance or into which direction some feature or feature combinations influence the target where that latter part is ultimately even more important than the prediction part.
Here is a schematic example for illustration:
Table1                       Table2
ID     T  F1-1  F1-2  F1-3   ID  F2-1  F2-2    F2-2
01  22.4  true  17    "x"    01  -3.3  "high"  "K5"
                             01  3.34  "mid"   "K1"
02  13.1  true  19    "x"    02  2.6   "mid"   "A3"
                             02  3.3   "low"   "K1"
                             02  3.1   "low"   "K1"

So I need a model that predicts/explains the value of T with the features F1-1, F1-2 and F1-3 from table1 and all the features F2-1..F2-3 of all rows with the same ID from  table2.
Features can be numeric, date, string, boolean. The target is numeric but if all else fails, could get discretized into a handful of values (e.g. very low / low / medium / high / very high )
This does not have to be a single model, single run or single approach either, if it is necessary to run an algorithm several times to get that information, that would be ok.
What is important here is that rather than individual rows in the "bag" (table 2) influencing the result while others are negative, the assumption is that all rows influence the result (up to noise) in some positive or negative way, none of the targets would be the same value if just one row in table 2 would be missing (so very different from the multi-instance learning assumption used for classification).
Is there anything out there which solves these problems? Are there any open-source libraries ideally in Python which help with this or which one could build upon?
